# Should there be a comma in "You again?"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

The original sentence is:

> You again?

In which, I am wondering if I should insert a comma after *"You"*:

> You, again?

Which one is more correct, and why?

Comment: I can't think of any commonly available references that could be used to easily answer this question.

Comment: I tried searching around for references, but couldn't find any. Could any of the close-voters explain why this question is off-topic? @Chenmunka?

Comment: Why do you think it would matter?

Comment: Nice summary on usage of commas http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/summary

Comment: Related and possibly of interest: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87564/the-vocative-case-and-comma-splices, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/is-it-a-splice-comma-if-an-interjection-phrase-is-involved, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206310/hello-comma-john, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both can be correct.

It depends on how you want to say it. Do you want a pause after *you* or not? In other words it's up to you. Use the comma to represent a pause in speech. Omit the comma if there is no pause after *you* in the speech you are representing in written form.