# Semicolons, full-stops and comma-splices

Tags: semicolons, periods, comma-splices, sentence-fragments

I came across these two sentences whilst editing today, and wondered what your opinions on the correct variations would be:

> They're great, I love them.
> vs.
> They're great; I love them.
> vs.
> They're great. I love them.

And

> She grew up acting and singing; treading the boards.
> vs.
> She grew up acting and singing, treading the boards.

I'm not averse to comma splicing, and as it's a piece of website copy it may indeed be appropriately vocative, but would love your opinions on the correct constructions.

Comment: If you're not averse to comma splicing, what do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: This is a comma splice: *They're great, I love them.* This is not: *She grew up acting and singing, treading the boards.* This is incorrect: *She grew up acting and singing; treading the boards.*

Comment: Correctness would depend on formality of source: a sales website is very different to a university or government one. But if you're happy with comma splices, the question seems based in opinion not grammar.

Comment: Thank-you @TinfoilHat, this is the kind of response that I was hoping for.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/87564/2303).

Comment: All three given variants (plus the use of a dash) of the first sentence is / sentences are fine in the correct settings. Different pause-weights are available. // I'd avoid the unusual use of a semicolon before what is essentially a second ing-clause unless other commas pushed me into it. The comma is fine before what is arguably an appositive.

Answer (score -1):

> They're great. I love them.

seems to indicate clipped speech, or a bit of hostility.

> They're great; I love them.

works, but a semicolon is better used for a pause when a comma doesn't work, or cause and effect, like "He began eating a lot and not exercising; he gained a lot of weight." or "It's no wonder the airplane doesn't fly very well; it doesn't have wings." (A "-" could also work in the place of the semicolon in this sentence).

> They're great, I love them.

seems the best option.

> She grew up acting and singing; treading the boards

works better because "treading the boards" is an attribute gained from acting and singing; she was "treading the boards" because she was acting and singing.

Comment: I can't think of a circumstance where "They're great. I love them." could be hostile.

Comment: I've downvoted because this would be a very unusual use of a semicolon. I see 'treading the boards' as  a reformulation and/or expansion of 'acting and singing', where a comma is fine, or a dash for a reformulation.